# How to perform lookup from textfield value and populate form elements without reloading page?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a very simple Form which has a textfield called `CustomerNumber`. There are other elements in the Form such as selects and lists that need to contain values related to the `CustomerNumber`.

All I want to do is:

1. User enters in a value into the `CustomerNumber` textfield and then 'tabs' out or just clicks somewhere else on the page
2. the value entered in `CustomerNumber` should then be passed as to a database query which will return the results that are based on the `CustomerNumber` value (e.g. customer's previous orders)
3. The results from the database query are used to populate the other Form elements
4. Finally once the user has filled in the form correctly, they will submit the entire form (including the CustomerNumber) to the server for processing

I just had a little look at JQuery and tried some simple DOM manipulation (e.g. `paragraph.text("new value")`) and the first I noticed is that none of the HTML in the Sourcecode gets changed. Within the browser I can see the change but not in the HTML.

This leads me to wonder that if I user JQuery to manipulate Form elements (through an AJAX call or something - I don't know Jquery yet), how will the database data returned from the AJAX call populate the Form elements and how will it actually get submitted to the server when they don't exist in the HTML?

I tried doing it using just HTML forms and have a submit button next to the `CustomerNumber` textfield and do a self-submit page, but that would mean having a Form within a Form which isn't possible...

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this is with the bind attribute of cfinput.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the tip. I was thinking to do just that but thought that CF is simply generating the javascript on my behalf which means I am losing some control...??

Comment: *how will it actually get submitted to the server when they don't exist in the HTML* As long as the form elements exist (and are valid) whatever value(s) they contain at the time of submission will be sent to the server. Regardless of whether the value was entered manually by a user or programatically w/Jquery. *Re: CF is simply generating the javascript on my behalf* Correct. It has a few quirks, and also uses older versions of most of the js libraries like ExtJS. Personally, I would recommend using jquery instead, or using ExtJS directly.

Comment: @Leigh so you're saying that if the Form 'visually' show the data I want, but in the View Source of the page it doesn't exist in the HTML, the data will still be submitted to the server? This is the bit I couldn't get my head around. When I manipulated a <p> element it changed on the page, but in the HTML source the old text was still there.

Comment: You might be thinking about stuff that simply doesn't matter.  First, not having control over js that ColdFusion generates with cfform.  That code works.  Second is what appears when you view the html source.  The important thing is that all the form fields get posted when you submit the form.

Comment: Don't use `cfinput` it will only cause headaches down the road. (And shame on you @DanBracuk for suggesting as much - -10 points from Grynffindor). If you use jQuery, you can handle this as easy (or easier than `cfinput` and binding stuff. The methods on jQuery you want to look at are `on()` (to fire off the process when the form field changes) and `ajax()` (to actually fetch the data - using a callback, you can handle what to do with the data when it is returned). You would want to return the data as JSON so it is easier to use.

Comment: @volumeone - Yes, as long as the controls have a `name` and ([abide by the rules for successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)). You are looking at the HTML source when the page was first loaded. That does not mean it cannot change or you cannot *add* form fields. It is no different than if a user enters a new `value` in a form field - the new `value` is not part of the original HTML source, but will still be submitted. You can test this yourself with a simple `<form method="post">`. Change the `value` programatically, submit it and dump the `FORM` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your question of "the source code doesn't seem to change...", that happens because your browser loads the html that came from the server in a DOM tree, in memory...

DOM from Document Object Model, is a tree containing all the nodes in your HTML including the  ones, and every time the browser finds a script node it executes it's code and keeps parsing so he can build up the DOM (this is the typical process of parsing a page).

When you do a mouse right click and pick the source code of the page you will the the HTML that your browser received, not the processed one.

To further understand what I'm talking about, the try to open your simple example of writting to a

element with google chrome, and after that open the Developer Toolbar (should be in the Tools>Developer Tools) or just right click inspect over the new introduced text.

You will see that the things you did via javascript are now present in the DOM, that because the Developer Tools will show you the source code based on the in memory DOM object and not based on the source code received.

To get a response from the server without refreshing the page just do a $.getjson (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to a page on your server that returns your response based on some querystring parameter.

Note, your server page can be you current page, assuming your page is called myform.php, you can do a $.getJSON('myform.aspx?action=getfieldvalue&field=customername', callback), then in your page you would have something like this:

```
(in the Page_Load event or in the top of your page for PHP)

if(QueryString["action"]=="getfieldvalue" && QueryString["customername"]!=null){
   Response.Clear();
   Response.Write("{name:""" + DataModel.GetCustomerName(QueryString["customername"]) + """}"); 
   Response.End();
}
```

The above code is just a draft, parameter parsing considerations, alternatives for page callbacks and optimizations were not taken into account.

Hope this helps,

Regards.